# Issue with string comparison in PHP

Tags: php, string-comparison

I have two strings with seemingly the same values. One is stored as a key in an array, the other a value in another different array. I compare the two using ==, ===, and strcmp. All treat them as different strings. I do a var_dump and this is what I get.

```
string(17) "Valentine’s Day" 
string(15) "Valentine's Day"
```

Does anyone have any idea why the first string would be 17 characters and the second 15?

Update: This is slightly more obvious when I pasted this out of my editor whose font made the two different apostrophe's almost indistinguishable.

Comment: looks like an issue with different character encodings, notice that the apostrophe is different in each case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first string contains a Unicode character for the apostrophe while the second string just has a regular ASCII ' character.

The Unicode character takes up more space.

If you run the PHP `ord()` function on each of those characters you'll see that you get different values for each:

```
echo ord("’"); //226 This is just the first 2 bytes (see comments below for details from ircmaxell)
echo ord("'"); //27
```

Comment: Bingo.  It's all in the apostrophe.

Comment: Just to clarify a little, "takes up more space" means that that unicode character takes multiple bytes to represent. PHP is not currently multibyte safe. For that, there are mb_* functions.

Comment: Pedantic note: the `226` result is only the first of the 3 bytes that make up that character (`226` is the starting block for a 3 byte block).  So there's 2 more bytes that `ord` silently discards (which is why you see the extra 2 characters)...

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to @Mark answer above which is right (the `’` is a multi-byte character, most probably UTF-8, while `'` is not). You can easily convert it to ASCII (or ISO-8859-1) using [iconv](http://php.net/iconv), per example:

```
echo iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $str);
```

**Note:** Not all characters can be transformed from multi-byte to ASCII or latin1. You can use `//IGNORE` to have them removed from the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

’ != '

mainly. if you want this not to be an issue, you could do something like this.

if (str_replace('’', '\'', "Valentine’s Day") == "Valentine's Day") {